# How can I display include item has 0 like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display item with ranking. And I want to display the item even that has no like. I tried to write code like below. But item with 0 like isn't displayed. Do you have a good idea?

```
  def show
    @all_ranks = Item.find(Like.group(:item_id).order('count(item_id) desc').pluck(:item_id))
    @ranking_item = @all_ranks.select{ |item| item.category_id == @category.id }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [LEFT JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join).

Also you can kind of optimize your method using *where* statement to get the items with specific category only. So your method can look like that:

```
def show    
  @rating_items = Item.select('items.id', 'COUNT(*) AS likes_count')
                      .joins('JOIN likes ON likes.item_id = items.id')
                      .where('items.category_id' => @category.id)
                      .group('items.id')
                      .order('likes_count DESC')
end
```

And than in a view you can use the code like that:

```
<% @rating_items.each do |item| %>
  <p><%= "#{item.id} - #{item.likes_count}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I don't know what Rails version you use. In case of Rails 5.* you can take a look at [left_joins](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) method. So for Rails 5.* you can try:

```
def show    
  @rating_items = Item.select('item.id', 'COUNT(*) AS likes_count')
                      .left_joins(:likes)
                      .where('items.category_id' => @category.id)
                      .group('items.id')
                      .order('likes_count DESC')
end
```

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: item.id: SELECT item.id, COUNT(*) AS votes_count FROM "items" LEFT OUTER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."item_id" = "items"."id" WHERE "items"."category_id" = ? GROUP BY items.id ORDER BY likes_count DESC

Comment: it has to be itemS.id, my bad